# Socket constructor missing

Tags: sockets, f#, mono, overloading, constructor-overloading

This program:

```
open System.Net.Sockets    
let s = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
```

Fails with this error-message on mono:

> error FS0505: The member or object constructor 'Socket' does not take 2 argument(s). An overload was found taking 1 arguments.

And this error-message on [TryF#](http://www.tryfsharp.org/create/debois/socket.fsx):

> error FS0501: The member or object constructor 'Socket' takes 3 argument(s) but is here given 2. The required signature is 'Socket(addressFamily: AddressFamily, socketType: SocketType, protocolType: ProtocolType) : unit'.

Documentation [says otherwise](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh264899(v=vs.110).aspx).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This code works fine for me in Visual Studio. In Try F#, the code is running against Silverlight version of .NET framework, which does not have all the overloads available in full .NET and so the overload taking 2 arguments is missing.

You can see this if you scroll to the "Version Information" section on the two MSDN pages:

- [Socket Constructor (AddressFamily, SocketType, ProtocolType)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2b86d684(v=vs.110).aspx) mentions Silverlight
- [Socket Constructor (SocketType, ProtocolType)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh264899(v=vs.110).aspx) only lists .NET 4.5, 4.5.1 and 4.5.2.

I suppose you should be able to use:

```
let s = new Socket(AddressFamily.Unspecified, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
```

Although I suspect that Silverlight might have other restrictions on sockets for security reasons, so if you want to do networking in F#, it is probably better to get a desktop version.